# Cause of MapServer Internal Server Error: Premature end of script headers: mapserv.exe?

Tags: mapserver, installation

I have changed MapServer version up to 6.2, changed folders Apache/cgi-bin and Apache/php, and replaced file cgi-bin/libmap.dll with ignore/oracle/libmap.dll.

When I type 'mapserv -v' in cmd it shows me 'input=oraclespatial', but when I try to open in browser localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe there is 'Internal Server Error' and 'Premature end of script headers: mapserv.exe' in logs

Comment: It used to work before update? How did you do the original installation and where do the update files come?

Comment: It used to work on MS4W v. 3.0.4 which works on MapServer v. 6.0.3. I downloaded the update files from http://www.maptools.org/dl/ms4w/mapserver_ms4w-6.2.0-beta4.zip. It works just fine without the Oracle Spatial libmap.dll file. As soon as I replace the file with the one that includes oracle spatial (located in ignored-libmap) it starts to give me the 'premature end of script header' errors every time I try to access the service.

Comment: Mixing different Mapserver and GDAL binaries tends to make troubles. I recommend to write to MS4W-users which is very low traffic but right persons do read it. Report your problem and encourage to make a new MS4W package. The latest release is from May 26, 2012.